# Why is my loading screen not showing up using QThread?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread

I'm making a desktop application in which once databases are being loaded I want to display a loading screen. A simple search led me to use gif files in QLabel with QThread object. But in my case QThread will not show anything.
The thread works fine, but there is something wrong with my implementation, and I cannot figure out what. My sample code is as follows:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QDialog, QApplication, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie
import sys
import time


class myThread(QThread):
    def run(self):

        test = QWidget()   # Only creating this to give parent to QDialog and QLabel objects in upcoming lines
        dialog = QDialog(test)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        lbl = QLabel(test)
        self.moviee = QMovie('Loading.gif')
        lbl.setMovie(self.moviee)
        self.moviee.start()
        vbox.addWidget(lbl)
        dialog.setLayout(vbox)
        dialog.show()

    def stop(self):
        self.moviee.stop()


class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        print('Thread is to be called here...')
        thread = myThread()
        thread.run()

        print('Thread has been called...')

        btn= QPushButton('Test button')
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(btn)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

        time.sleep(5)     # sleep function used to emulate funcitons in actual program

        # thread.stop()
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The block of code with `QMovie` object works fine when it is in the `Main` loop, so there is definitely somthing wrong with my implementation of `QThread`.

Comment: Are you trying to call `thread.run()`, but QThread could only be started via `start()`. https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtCore/QThread.html#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.QThread.run

Comment: No GUI element access (including creation) should happen outside the main Qt thread. No blocking function (such as a call to `sleep`) should ever happen inside the main Qt thread. QThreads are exactly those that have to be implemented and used to do the "heavy work", and everything related to the GUI should be in the main Qt thread, not the other way around.

Comment: @VladimirBershov Same happens with `thread.run()` method. No clue.

Comment: @musicamante I understand your suggestion, which I totally agree with also. But my question is about the implementation of `QThread` . Can you explain why is this not working?

Comment: @AsadUllahButt you cannot create GUI elements in non-main threads. This will not work.

Comment: @AsadUllahButt Assuming you already corrected what Vladimir reported (the thread should be started by calling `start()`), it's not working **exactly** because of the reason I told before: QMovie interacts with QLabel, which is a GUI object, and as such it **must** always be accessed only from the main Qt thread. You *cannot* create/access/modify a QWidget (including playing a QMovie in a QLabel) from another thread. You *have* to leave the creation of the QLabel *and* playing of the QMovie within the main thread. That's just how Qt works (an, AFAIK, as all GUI based frameworks do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code. As @musicamante remarkes, you cannot create widget outside of the main thread. This means you can't create the dialog within `myThread.run`. Instead you could move the management of the dialog to `Main` and use slots and signals to open and close the dialog.

Secondly, all time-consuming tasks like your `time.sleep(5)` should be put in `myThread.run`.

With this in mind, you could do something like this

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QDialog, QApplication, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie
import sys
import time


class myThread(QThread):
    def run(self):
        # time consuming actions
        time.sleep(5)


class Main(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        print('Thread is to be called here...')
        self.load()
        print('Thread has been called...')

        btn= QPushButton('Test button')
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(btn)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.show()

    def load(self):
        # setup dialog
        dialog = QDialog(self)
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        lbl = QLabel(self)
        self.moviee = QMovie('Loading.gif')
        lbl.setMovie(self.moviee)
        self.moviee.start()
        vbox.addWidget(lbl)
        dialog.setLayout(vbox)

        # setup thread
        thread = myThread()
        thread.finished.connect(thread.deleteLater)
        thread.finished.connect(dialog.close)
        thread.finished.connect(dialog.deleteLater)
        thread.start()

        dialog.exec()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Thankyou very much mate. My program has a bit long startup time (7-8 seconds) during which it **(1.)** builds the GUI in the `Main` class, **(2.)** draws some graphs, **(3.)** builds some databases etc. So I wanted to move the 1st part (i.e. creation of GUI) to the thread. If that is not possible, what convention is being followed in the developers community? How do I make my program look that it is being loaded very quickly, without moving the GUI creation in the thread class?