# PyQt - Qdialog in a QThread did'nt show while needed

Tags: python, pyqt, qthread, qdialog

I am looking to display a QDialog during a QThread. I have looked at several tutorials like this one: [Why is my loading screen not showing up using QThread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61179145/why-is-my-loading-screen-not-showing-up-using-qthread)

But it doesn't work. In my situation, I want to display the QDialog during the connection attempt to an instrument with PyVisa which is done in the QThread.

Currently, it does the QThread and then displays my QDialog.

I would like to understand the logic behind QThreads

My main :

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from baa_connexion import BAA
myApp = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
myApp.setStyle('Fusion')

#application
window = BAA()
window.show()

#Close programm
myApp.quit()
myApp.exec_()
```

baa_connexion.py :

```
import pyvisa
import logging
    
from VirtualInstrument import VirtualInstrument
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, Qt
 
class BAA(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  
        self.information_settings()

    def open_connexion(self):
        
        self.qdiag = QtWidgets.QDialog(self.centralwidget)
        self.hbox_dial = QtWidgets.QLabel("Connection....")
        self.hbox_con = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.qdiag)
        self.hbox_con.addWidget(self.hbox_dial)

        self.Worker = QWorkerthread()
        self.Worker.finished.connect(self.Worker.deleteLater)
        self.Worker.finished.connect(self.qdiag.close)
        self.Worker.finished.connect(self.qdiag.deleteLater)
        self.Worker.start()
        self.status_thread = self.Worker.connexion_asa()

        if self.status_thread == True :                
            print("Connect OK")
            return True
        else:
            print("No connected")               
            return False    
        self.qdiag.setLayout(self.hbox_con)
        self.qdiag.exec()

    def information_settings(self):
      
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.enter = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.enter.clicked.connect(self.suite)

        self.hbox_infos = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)          
        self.hbox_infos .addWidget(self.enter)
        self.setLayout(self.hbox_infos)    
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)   
  
class QWorkerthread(Qt.QThread):
    #worker_finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal(bool)
    #finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def connexion_asa(self):
        self.rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
        self.fichier = open("ipasa.txt", 'r')
        self.ip = self.fichier.read()
        try:
            self.inst = self.rm.open_resource("TCPIP0::" + self.ip + "::inst0::INSTR", timeout=25000)
            logging.info("Connection Ok")
            return True
        except:
            logging.error('No connection with Spectral Analyzer')
            #self.worker_finished.emit(True)
            return False
        self.finished.emit()
```

**UPDATE :**

```
import pyvisa
import logging
import time

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, Qt

class BAA(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.information_settings()

    def open_connexion(self):
        self.qdiag = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.hbox_con = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox_dial = QtWidgets.QLabel("Connection....")
        self.hbox_con.addWidget(self.hbox_dial)
        self.qdiag.setLayout(self.hbox_con)

        Worker = myThread()
        Worker.status_connect.connect(self.receive_status)     #SIGNAL
        Worker.finished.connect(Worker.deleteLater)
        Worker.finished.connect(self.qdiag.close)
        Worker.finished.connect(self.qdiag.deleteLater)

        Worker.start()
        self.qdiag.exec()

    def receive_status(self, etat):
        print(etat)
        if etat == False:
            print("Connection failed")
            return False
        else:
            print("OK Conenct")
            return True

    def new_sheet(self):
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.bjr = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)

        self.open_connexion()
        
        #IF status_connect IS TRUE :
            #self.bjr.setText("Ok Conenct")
        #else:
             #self.bjr.setText("No connection")
        
        self.gh = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gh.addWidget(self.bjr)
        self.setLayout(self.gh)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    def information_settings(self):

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.enter = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.enter.clicked.connect(self.new_sheet)

        self.hbox_infos = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.hbox_infos.addWidget(self.enter)
        self.setLayout(self.hbox_infos)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
class myThread(Qt.QThread):
    status_connect = Qt.pyqtSignal(bool)
    def run(self):
        # time consuming actions

        self.rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
        self.fichier = open("ipasa.txt", 'r')
        self.ip = self.fichier.read()
        try:
            self.inst = self.rm.open_resource("TCPIP0::" + self.ip + "::inst0::INSTR", timeout=25000)
            self.status_connect.emit(True)
        except:
            self.status_connect.emit(False)
            print("oh")
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Sorry but your code is really confusing (please read more about [formatting code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362)), and it's also unclear how the thread is started, how it works, or to what the "QDialog" part belongs. Please take your time and provide a ***valid*** [mre]. Besides: 1. QThread already has a [`finished`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#finished) signal; 2. you should not emit it by yourself; 3. creating a class called `Qthread` is a ***terrible*** naming choice and a perfect recipe to lots of unnecessary bugs and headaches.

Comment: Hey @musicamante I modified the reading of the code, I hope that it corresponds (the colours are not apparent, I however used the tutorials and the {} button). I hope you can see it more clearly. I changed the name of my class too

Comment: Sorry, but that is certainly *not* minimal. Read the link above more carefully and remove all unnecessary parts (including all those irrelevant imports).

Comment: I modified it, I can't make it shorter while keeping the essential information

Comment: You're not running `connexion_asa` in the thread, you're directly calling it, making the thread useless. Everything that has to be run in the thread must be implemented (or called) in `run()`, which will be executed when calling the thread `start()`. Also: 1. `return` is useless in a function that is connected to a signal; 2. remove `myApp.quit()`.

Comment: It works, thank you! I have a question about returns. I'm trying to find out with the `try`in the thread which truth comes out True or False. How can I do to get it in the main  `open_connection` function pls?

Comment: You cannot, not like this. Threads work asynchronously, if you try to wait for a return, you'll block the event loop and prevent the UI to work properly until the called function returns control (which is what you did before). You need to use signals for that. Instead of using `finished`, create a custom signal with a bool argument, and emit it from the thread, then connect that signal to whatever function you need.

Comment: Hello, it works, thank you! But I have to use a function argument to get its bool. I would like to get it as a normal variable, how to do it? I have to use a function argument to get its bool as a normal variable, how do I do that? The usefulness of my signal is that the application continues to work only if the signal is True. I have updated the code

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean. Do you want to quit the application if the thread emits a `False` signal? Then just call `QApplication.quit()`. Do you want to close the dialog? Then `self.qdiag.close()`.

Comment: The QDialog is currently closed after the thread has finished. In fact, the Thread only allows me to display a Dialog preventing a connection to a device. I would like to know at the end of this Thread if the connection, so my `status_connect`(bool) signal is   `True `  or `False`.  If it is `False` I have to press the button again to restart this Thread, if it is `True` it is Ok. But I would like to know how to handle this status_connection signal.

Comment: Currently, I can only get its info with a function `receive_status` and an argument. I would like to not need this method or know how to use it in my situation
In my update code, I put a situation where I need the result of the signal.

Comment: You cannot use "variables", because the very nature of threading is to have *asynchronous* functions. Since the only way to *properly* work with threads is through signals and slots/functions, you *do* need a function. As already said, return values of functions connected to signals are completely useless, you have to implement the *next* behavior in those functions, for instance by re-enabling (or showing) the button that would eventually restart the thread. Just create a button (disabled by default) that would try to restart the thread, and enable it whenever the signal is `False`.

Comment: How can I program to query the behaviour and know if the signal returned False. I imagine it's with an If. That's what I can't figure out, the response of the signal.

Comment: I believe you still don't understand the mechanics of signals and slots: you don't "query" anything, you do something when the signal is emitted. The signal/slot mechanism follows the [observer pattern](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), which doesn't "wait" for something to happen, but *does* something *when* something happens (similarly to *callbacks*). I strongly suggest you to read more about the subject, starting with the [official Qt documentation](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) and some [other resources](//www.elpauer.org/stuff/a_deeper_look_at_signals_and_slots.pdf).